# How to tell Occur to show the line in the top of the buffer

Tags: hooks, motion, occur

I usually use `occur` to make an index of the beginning of different things. When I jump to the occurrence, `Occur` shows the line in the middle of the buffer. How can I instruct `occur` to show the occurrence in the top of the buffer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll the window in `occur-mode-find-occurrence-hook` such that point is at the top of the window:

```el
(defun my-occur-recenter ()
  "Scroll point to the top of the window."
  (recenter 0))

(add-hook 'occur-mode-find-occurrence-hook #'my-occur-recenter)
```

Notes:

1. The functions registered in `occur-mode-find-occurrence-hook` are called with point at the position of the selected occurence.
2. `recenter` called with a non-negative argument adjusts the vscroll of the window such that point is located that many lines from the top line.

Comment: hi, if the registered functions are *called with point*, how does it work without error if the function is parameterless like it is here?

Comment: @MustafaAydın They are not called with an argument but with point at the occurence.